# Potential issue with one of Oracle's trails on Java generics

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I was reviewing one of the Oracle trails on Java generics, entitled "[Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)", and I could not convince myself of an explanation given.  Curious, I tested the code locally and I could not even reproduce the behavior which the trail explains.  Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

The Oracle trail claims the following behavior for this code snippet:

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");     
Integer x = mn.data;    // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
```

This code snippet should look like the following after type erasure:

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = (MyNode)mn;         // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");
Integer x = (String)mn.data; // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
```

I did not understand the casts being used here or the behavior.  When I tried running this code locally using IntelliJ with Java 7, I got this behavior:

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");     // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
Integer x = mn.data;
```

In other words, the JVM will not allow a `String` to be used with `setData()`.  This is actually intuitive to me, and it agrees with my understanding of generics.  Since `MyNode` `mn` was constructed with `Integer`, the compiler should be casting every call to `setData()` with `Integer` to ensure type safety (i.e. an `Integer` is being passed in).

Can someone shed some light on this apparent bug in the Oracle trail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misread the Oracle page. If you read all the way to the end, you'll find it states that what happens is what you describe.

It's not a well-written page; the author says "blah happens" when what they mean is "IF THIS WERE THE CASE THEN blah happens BUT AS WE'LL SEE THAT IS NOT THE CASE". They are being too loose with their language.

The point of the page - bridge methods - is to explain how the real behaviour is as you observed, when the predicted behaviour (based on Generics acutal design + implementation) is what they "suggested" at the start.

Comment: I think saying the page is loose with its language is giving it too much credit.  So what you are saying is that the call `n.setData("Hello")` is actually hitting the bridge method generated by the compiler, which will cast every object being passed to it to `Integer` before calling the super method.  Well this explains everything I suppose, thanks for the insights.

Comment: I tend to be scathing about bad docs, but I've grown accustomed to corps publishing terrible docs, especially for APIs. Ironically, Java had some of the best docs ever, when it was young. Nowadays ... I try to keep my contempt to myself :).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's explained in the trail.

In *theory*, when the class `Node` is compiled, its base type `T` is erased to `Object`.

So in reality, it is compiled into something like

```
class Node {
    public Object data;

    public Node(Object data) {this.data = data; }

    public void setData(Object data) {
         System.out.println("Node.setData");
         this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Then you create a child class `MyNode`, that has its own `setData(Integer data)`. As far as Java is concerned, this is an **overload** of the `setData` method, not an override of it. Each `MyNode` object has two `setData` methods. One is `setData(Object)` it inherited from `Node`, and the other is `setData(Integer)`.

So basically, if you use the raw type, and you call `setData` with any reference that is not an `Integer`, Java's normal interpretation of this would be to call the overload `setData(Object)`.

This would not cause a problem on assignment, because `data` is declared as `Object`, not as `Integer`. The problem would be only when you try to assign the data back to an `Integer` reference. This plain behavior of Java would cause the `MyNode` object to be "contaminated" with inappropriate data.

However, as the trail says, the compiler adds a "bridge" method to make the child class behave more like the way you intuitively think of it. It adds an **override** of `setData(Object)` to `MyNode`, so that you cannot call the original, non-safe `Node.setData(Object)`. In this overriding bridge method, there is an explicit cast to `Integer` that ensures that you will not be able to assign a non-integer reference to the `data`.

And that's the behavior you see when you actually compile and run the example.

If you run `javap -p` on the `MyNode.class` file, you'll see that indeed, it has two `setData` methods:

```
class MyNode extends Node<java.lang.Integer> {
  public MyNode(java.lang.Integer);
  public void setData(java.lang.Integer);
  public void setData(java.lang.Object);
}
```